# Extracting boundary of blob from grayscale image given prior information about its location

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I would like to extract the contours of the bright blobs on the top-right of these images (the image itself is grayscale, but I've manually labeled roughly what I want to extract using red):

[image]
[image]

I'm having difficulty with the fact that there is quite a bit of noise (especially in the second image), so simple edge detection returns a lot of spurious/disconnected edges and I'd have to fine-tune the parameters too much for it to work on a general image.

The second approach I considered was to binarize the image and then use region growing, but again the problem with that is the threshold for binarization.

Lastly, due to licensing reasons, I can't use patented blob detection algorithms like SURF and SIFT. What I would like to do is to somehow exploit my prior knowledge about the location of the blob. I can safely assume that it will always be on the to-right corner of the image, and that it will roughly have the same shape as in the above images, although the size can vary.

P.S. If it helps, overestimating the boundary isn't too much of an issue, but I cannot afford to have a smaller boundary that doesn't encompass the entire blob. Also, while it would be ideal to have an end-to-end solution, even a suggestion of a general approach or links to relevant literature that might work are also welcome.

Comment: who cares about software patents? no one will ever find out. SIFT or SURF are not the right tool here anyway. as you already know where to look for it simple region growing will do. or just use a fixed roi or ignore saturated pixels in general.

Comment: "who cares about software patents? no one will ever find out": if for commercial purposes, this would be unfair.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't provide the original, untouched images. Anyway, simple binarization will do, followed by connected components analysis and selection of the largest blob.